# Is there a way to hide scroll indicators in a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to create a SwiftUI List, but not show scroll indicators. ScrollView offers showsIndicators to do this. How can it be done?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Any Indicators (List, scrollView, etc.)

you can get rid of showing indicators for all `List`s, but with an API of the `UITableView`. because SwiftUI `List` is using `UITableView` for iOS behind the scene:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0...100, id: \.self) { item  in
            Text("hey")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will eliminate all `TableView`s and `List`s indicators. You should make it visible again if you need to.

---

<sub>**⚠️ Not Yet Important Note**</sub>

Seems like Apple is removing `appearance` hacks (but not for this one **yet**). So you can use `LazyVStack` inside and `ScrollView` instead of `List` and use the available argument for hiding the indicators.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) { // <- This argument
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)").frame(height: 40)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work great for now?  late 2021

Comment: May not be ideal for everyone because as of iOS 15, List has the refreshable modifier.

Answer (score 38):

It is actually easy to accomplish this without any appearance work arounds in the answer accepted. You just have to use the ScrollView initializer and set the parameter `showsIndicators` to false.

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
     // ... your content for scrollView
}
```

Inside your ScrollView you could use `LazyVStack`, if you have a lot of subviews to scroll through. SwiftUI will then render very efficiently your subviews: **"lazy"** -> only if needed).

Comment: ScrollView is not good for performance because all of its views are created immediately and not when needed like List of LazyVStack.

Comment: @FarouK, the question was "How to hide the indicators?", the question was not, "when would LazyVStack be a better solution than ScrollView?", so your comment seems to be a bit misplaced here.

Comment: But your solution has a big side effect on performance and you didn't mention that.

Comment: @FarouK: Well, the questions stands for itself. The decision was already made by the questioner to use a ScrollView (but without indicators). And that is - by the way - no performance problem unless you have more then 20 subviews. So your comment seems to be a little bit smartassy.

Comment: The question is actually how to hide the scroll indicators in a SwiftUI List; they just used ScrollView as an example of how it is done elsewhere

Answer (score 11):

Hide scrolling indicator now became very simple

```
   List {}.scrollIndicators(ScrollIndicatorVisibility.hidden)
```

Comment: You should mention from when this is available: 'scrollIndicators(_:axes:)' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer

Comment: You can also do dot syntax directly: `List {}.scrollIndicators(.hidden)`

Answer (score 9):

The choosen answer won't work in iOS 16. They released a new `viewModifier` called `.scrollIndicators(.hidden)`. I created a viewModifier wrapper which you can call like this on your `List`: `.modifier(HideListIndicatorsViewModifier())`

```
struct HideListIndicatorsViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Until there is a native SwiftUI way to achieve this, the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library provides a decent solution.

After applying all modifiers to your list just add as a last modifier the following:

```
List {
  ...
}
.introspectTableView { tableView in
  tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false // here you can access any other UITableView property
}
```

I hope there is a native way to do that at some point.

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 4):

## New in iOS 16

A new modifier has been added in iOS 16, you can now use

```swift
List {
    ...
}
.scrollIndicators(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

List basically creates a tableview (UpdateCoalescingTableView) behind the scenes, and tableview's are scrollable. Unfortunately, however, you can't get to the scrollview attributes in SwiftUI.

You "might" be able to create a UIViewRepresentable that could walk up the view hierarchy until it finds a scrollview, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You could also create your own scrollview, put a vstack inside it, and "fake" a list view, which would probably be the safer approach.

Comment: But it is not the same component underneath List enables for example pagination very easly and adding new data smartly reloads List content, but Scroll View with ForEach VStack just look like UIScrollView with VerticalStack nothing more, I consider wether there won't be some performance issues like not reusing cells

Comment: you can actually get to the underlying scrollview of List on iOS 13 and iOS14 using custom modifier and uiviewreprestable workarounds, while scrollview+vstack is not the same thing as list (lacks of laziness)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following on iOS 15 and below.

```swift
List {
  WhateverContent()
    .padding([.horizontal], 16) // Positive padding to compensate.
}
.padding([.horizontal], -16)    // Negative padding to put the vertical
                                // indicators out of the screen.
```

Suppose you don't like to change the global appearance of UITableView. I do this, and it works like a charm when the List occupies the whole screen width.